# Unsure about correct permissions in running Ruby Scripts

Tags: permissions, chmod

I get the following alert when I run a Ruby script

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/cs/Documents in PATH, mode 040777
```

The solution is to change the permissions. However, I am unsure which one is the appropriate one.

I use many user accounts for different purposes. I have one main account by which I run the commands at my cs -account.

**Which permissions would you give for the cs -account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `chmod og-w /Users/cs/Documents` and all should be well.

This will remove the "other" and "group" write access permissions.